# Ubuntu awk - Print filenames that contain anything other than digits

Tags: bash, awk

I wish to print all filenames that do not "contain only numbers":

This is my code so far:

```
find . -type f | awk '!/[[:digit:]]/ {print}'
```

This finds me every file not containing any digit.

My problem is also that, it checks directories names too.

Newest code:

```
find . -type f | awk '/.*\W.*/ {print}'
```

I think It works, but it also checks directories name, I care only about the files

Comment: rephrase the question, last line and first line doesn't match

Comment: no letters and numbers?

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry for problems, Can you check it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

To print all filenames that do not "contain only numbers":

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n'| awk '/[^[:digit:]]/ {print}'
```

No directories included.

---

If you want all filenames that do not "contain numbers or letters":

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n'| awk '/[^[:alnum:]]/ {print}'
```

But I believe that would be wise to include the dot `.` and the space .
Characters that are usually used in filenames:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n'| awk '/[^[:alnum:]. ]/ {print}'
```

---

The (Negated) [Shorthand Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\W` will also include the `_` underscore, and is less portable (is a GNU extension).

I do not know if you mean to include that or not.

Comment: I've edited the question, its my bad. But I've swapped the regex with `/.*\W.*/` and its works. Thanks !

Comment: @Piodo Please read the extended answer about letters and `\W`.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution would be

```
find . -type f -regextype sed -not -regex '^[./[:digit:]]\+$'
```

Here `-not -regex` is the equivalent of `!p` in sed.

If you're dealing with non-standard file names do :

```
find . -type f -regextype sed \
       -not -regex '^[./[:digit:]]\+$' \
       -print0 |  while read -r -d '' line
do 
  echo "$line"
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
./binaryzebra8
./foo
./bingo bar
./bar
./file
./romeo
juliet --> non-standard file name
./888/bingo88
./\hash --> non-standard file name
```

The `-printf "%f\n"` as mentioned in @BinaryZebra's answer gives you the basenames of the files as the [[ manpage ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says :

> %f File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last
>   element).

but in practice you need full path to files if you're indeed processing the results from find.

Answer (score 0):

How about relying on just `find`?

```
find . -type f -name '*[^0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, just I'm not going to use `awk` as it is harder to negate a search pattern with respect to a simple `grep -v`

```
find . -type f | grep -v '^[0-9]*$'
```